# OR elements in __m128

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

I'm writing some SSE code and I'd like to OR all elements inside my __m128. I can get all values individually and OR them that way but that seems inefficient.

Basically what I'm looking for is the orx instruction available on the SPU. It's a bit odd so there is no direct alternative, but is there a way to efficiently do this using SSE2?

In code I want to do:

```
p = _mm_cmpgt_ps(p, r);
x = p[0] | p[1] | p[2] | p[3]; // spu_orx(p)
```

I might be going at this all wrong and I just need to redesign the code so that I don't end up with this problem but I'm hoping someone with a lot more experience than me knows how to do this!

Comment: Do you really want the OR of each 32-bit value? If you just want to know if one of the 128-bits is non-zero then use `!_mm_testz_si128` from SSE4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will `OR` all 4 x 32 bit elements together:

```
p = _mm_or_si128(p, _mm_srli_si128(p, 8));
p = _mm_or_si128(p, _mm_srli_si128(p, 4));
```

Element 0 will contain the final value - you can extract this as an int if needed:

```
int result = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(p);
```

A couple of *caveats*:

Whenever you find yourself needing to perform a horizontal operation such as this, especially if it's part of a performance-critical inner loop, then often it can a sign that your SIMD implementation is inefficient and you might want to re-think it.

Also note that trying to port Cell SPU code to SSE line-by-line without looking at the "big picture" is probably not going to give you the best possible results.

Comment: Oh I should thank you for the many SSE/bit-fiddling answers you've given to the community :)

Comment: @legends2k: very kind of you - I quite enjoy doing it though!

Comment: I think you'd need to rotate, not shift, for each element to have the same value. Having shifted right the rightmost element should hold the reduction result. Such a rotation could be done using the shuffle operation.

Comment: @YannVernier: good catch - I copied and pasted from some old code without thinking about it too much - I'l fix the answer...

Comment: A select few horizontal operations do exist: phadd, phsub and phminpos. The first is useful for dot products such as distance calculation.

Comment: @YannVernier: true, and there are cases where this kind of operation can't be avoided, but most commonly horizontal operations are performed outside a loop, e.g. the final sum (or whatever) at the end of a reduction.

Comment: Thanks Paul! This seems to do what I want, but I'm now going to try and look into rewriting this with the "big picture" in mind. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP really wants (though it's what he says he wants). I think he just wants to know if a single bit is non zero. For that he can use `!_mm_testz_si128`

Comment: You may well be right - a little more context would be helpful - it sounds like the OP is porting Cell SPU code to SSE, and direct translation might result in inefficient idioms which do not fully exploit SSE, as mentioned above. If the OP would like to clarify and add some more context then there may well be a more "holistic" answer.

Comment: Well, I am trying to OR two _mm_cmpgt_ps comparisons and use the result as a mask somewhere else. At the moment I just took a step back and see if I could solve this problem differently and maybe learn some more about SSE before continuing. It seems like I might be able to use _mm_testz_si128, though I was trying to limit myself to SSE2. But that's not really a problem, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Life will definitely be easier if you can assume SSE4. Good luck!